# all_of asking for argument list

Tags: c++

After using all_of succesfully once I tried to do it again.

```
if (all_of(Enemies.begin(), Enemies.end(), in_lock_range))
            {
                lock_on = -1;
            }
```

The vector is:

`std::vector<Enemy> Enemies;`

The function is:

```
bool Player::in_lock_range(Enemy arg)
{
    if (get_distance(mouseTarget.x, mouseTarget.y, arg.x, arg.y) > arg.erect.r) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

get_distance(x1,x2,y1,y2) returns the distance from 2 points

Enemy is a friend class to Player and vice versa so they use each other's stuff freely.

The error I recieve is

```
error C3867: 'Player::in_lock_range': function call missing argument list; use '&Player::in_lock_range' to create a pointer to member
```

I'm not sure why he is apparently asing for agruments for in_lock_range when I don't believe it needs any when in all_of, as I have used it in a different situation with no such issue.

Can anyone please explain to me what the cause of this can be? I am not really experienced in this. Thanks.

Comment: I guess `Player::in_lock_range` is a non-static member, and `all_of` needs a static or a non-member. But there isn't enough code to know for sure. Also, `if (something) return true; else return false;` makes my teeth hurt.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm not sure how to write it otherwise. So do I need to remove in_lock_range from the Player class, or is there another way to do it? P.S. not familiar with static and non_static members.

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are too many unknowns in your question to post a useful answer.

Comment: I know, sorry, but I found that I can use this: 'if (all_of(Enemies.begin(), Enemies.end(), [](const Enemy& e){ return player.in_lock_range(e); }))'
allthough I have no idea how it works, it does. Also I can't figure out how to make something a code block in a comment...

Answer (score 0):

It's a member function, so the syntax for taking a pointer is

```
&Player::in_lock_range
```

This is only usable if it's a static member, since it must be callable with just a single argument. I'm guessing it isn't - presumably `mouseTarget` is a non-static data member of `Player`. In that case, you'll have to bind it to some player object:

```
bind(&Player::in_lock_range, std::ref(some_player), std::placeholders::_1)
```

or wrap it in a lambda:

```
[&](const Enemy& e){return some_player.in_lock_range(e);}
```

The function should probably take its argument by constant reference rather than value; and you might want to simplify the return statements

```
if (whatever) return true;
else return false;
```

to the more readable

```
return whatever;
```